# jsoup output wrong HTML when < exists inside text

Tags: jsoup, html-parser

Input html is

```
<p>猫<虎</p>
```

Which can be displayed by Chrome as
猫<虎

But when you use jsoup to parse the html,
then output html is

```
<p>猫
  <虎 < p>
  </虎<></p>
```

How can I fix this problem without modify the

```
< to &lt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think that jsoup is "wrong" and chrome is "right"? An `<` that is not part of a tag should always be escaped as `&lt;` (because it will otherwise be interpreted as [opening a tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#data-state)) - fix that, and all standards-compliant html tools will agree on the same parsing. Do not fix it, and some may disagree. In this case, JSoup is accepting non-alphanumerics as tag-name, which is [invalid](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#elements-2). But it encountered an unescaped `<` that was not part of a tag-name!

If you insist on not changing the source html, you can simply pre-process it before feeding it into JSoup:

```
 // before 
 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

 // with pre-processing
 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(fixOutOfTagLessThan(html));
```

where

```
 /**
  * Replaces not-in-tag `<` by `&lt;`, but WILL FAIL in 
  * many cases, because it is unaware of:
  * - comments (<!--)
  * - javascript
  * - the fact that you should NOT PARSE HTML WITH REGEX
  */
 public static void fixOutOfTagLessThan(String html) {
    return html.replaceAll("<([^</>]+)<", "&lt;$1<");
 }
```

Chrome appears to be applying HTML5 parse logic to [treat the `<` as text](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parse-error-invalid-first-character-of-tag-name) (since it is not part of a valid tag name) - however, as I understand it, it should reject everything up to the `>`, and then issue a missing `</p>`. So, to my eyes, it does not appear to follow the standard fully either.

Comment: Thank you. chrome and edge both show the same results. They have about 70% share of browser usage. That's a big deal. non-alphanumerics should not be treated as tag-name. But I accept you answer. Wish jsoup could comply with the chrome way.